# What does "global" mean in certain gem5 DPRINTF log messages where I expect a SimObject name instead?

Tags: gem5

While debugging a problem with `--debug-flag Cache`, I noticed that this printf:

```
bool
MSHR::handleSnoop(PacketPtr pkt, Counter _order)
{
    DPRINTF(Cache, "%s for %s\n", __func__, pkt->print());
```

prints as:

```
7306617000: Cache: global: handleSnoop for WriteReq [80a70800:80a70803] UC D=110e0000
```

which was a bit confusing since most `DPRINTF` lines have the full path to a simobject as in the `system.cpu5.dcache` for:

```
7306617000: Cache: system.cpu5.dcache: sendWriteQueuePacket: write WriteReq [80a70800:80a70803] UC D=110e0000
```

What does this `global` mean?

Tested in gem5 3ca404da175a66e0b958165ad75eb5f54cb5e772.

Answer (score 1):

global just means that the `DPRINTF` is being called from neither a SimObject, nor from a class that does implements the `name()` method.

By expanding the definition of `DPRINTF` we see that it calls `name()`:

```
#define DPRINTF(x, ...) do {                     \
    using namespace Debug;                       \
    if (DTRACE(x)) {                             \
        Trace::getDebugLogger()->dprintf_flag(   \
            curTick(), name(), #x, __VA_ARGS__); \
    }                                            \
} while (0)
```

and `name()` is defined on the `SimObject` base class:

```
    virtual const std::string name() const { return params()->name; }
```

However, if a class does not derive from `SimObject` nor implement a custom `name()`, it just resolves to the global `name()` declared in `src/base/trace.hh`:

```
// Return the global context name "global".  This function gets called when
// the DPRINTF macros are used in a context without a visible name() function
const std::string &name();
```

which is implemented as:

```
const std::string &name()
{
    static const std::string default_name("global");

    return default_name;
}
```

So on the above example, `MSHR` is not a `SimObject`, but `Cache` is.